How can I get italic bold math characters with `unicode-math` and `\mbfitA`?
I tried to get bold italic math characters, using the package unicode-math. According to the documentation (texdoc unimath), the command
\mbfitA

should do the trick. However I only get bold, italic letters when using it. The result is the same as when I use \mbfA. Curiously, when I try to use greek letters, I can only produce italic versions. So again, \mbftheta and \mbfittheta produce the same letter, but both are bold and italic versions. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \(\mbfA\mbfitA\)
    \(\mbftheta\mbfittheta\)
\end{document}

I also tried it with the Libertinus font via \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}, but while I can see the characters changing, they don't change to italic. I checked that the Libertinus Math font does have italic bold unicode math characters.
Any help would be appreciated :)


However I only get a bold [upright] letter "A" when using \mbfitA. The result is the same as when I use \mbfA. Curiously, when I try to use [lowercase] Greek letters, I can only produce italic versions.

By default, the unicode-math package preserves TeX's long-established default settings for bold uppercase-Roman letters (viz., always upright) and for bold or non-bold lowercase-Greek letters (viz., always slanted). The \mbf.. and \mbfit.. macros don't change the default settings. (Put differently, \usepackage{unicode-math} and \usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math} produce the same output.)
For the ultimate in control over font shapes, including the ability to always override whichever of the four available math-style options of the unicode-math package -- the options are TeX, ISO, french, and upright -- may be in effect, I recommend the use of the \symit, \symup, \symbfit, and \symbfup macros, also provided by the unicode-math package.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % default math style: "TeX"
\begin{document}
$aA\theta\Theta \quad
 \symit{aA\theta\Theta} \quad 
 \symup{aA\theta\Theta} \quad  
 \symbfit{aA\theta\Theta} \quad 
 \symbfup{aA\theta\Theta}$
\end{document}

